# Responsive Text Sizing Issues within container

Tags: css, responsive-design, typography

I am having the hardest time here...I have searched for a while now and can't quite figure out how to properly get my text to properly re-size in my parent container.

Here is the code:

```css
html,
body,
box,
thumbnail_image,
overlay,
h1,
h3,
h6,
p,
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

input {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  position: absolute;
  top;
  25.5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  border-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 .1em 0;
}

.heart_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.5px;
  right: 55px;
}

.heart_button:hover,
.heart_button:active,
.heart_button:focus {
  color: #dd0239;
}

.heart_background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: .1;
  width: 65px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.box {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 490px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #18a0ff;
  box-shadow: 1px 15px 50px 2px;
}

.quote_image {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .1;
  top: 62px;
  left: 51px;
}

.image_overlay {
  background-color: #282a37;
  width: 170px;
  height: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnail_image {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  opacity: .12;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text_container {
  left: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 338px;
  max-width: 90%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.7em;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}

.author_name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 206px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

h6 {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-weight: light;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 28px;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(209deg, #E5ECEF 40%, #BBC2C5 100%) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 649px) {

  .box {
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  
  .text_container {
    width: 280px;
    height: 236.6px;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="heart_button">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dp32vpqfu/image/upload/v1457311522/little_heart_jle1j3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="heart_background">
    </div>
    <div class="image_overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail_image">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dp32vpqfu/image/upload/v1457298445/Sheldon_Pic_l3cprk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text_container">
      <h1>Don't You think that if I were wrong, &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; I'd know it?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="author_name">
      <h3> - Sheldon Cooper </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="quote_image">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dp32vpqfu/image/upload/v1457314397/quotations_image_wfwimc.png">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dp32vpqfu/image/upload/v1457364436/arrow-left_moebxn.png">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dp32vpqfu/image/upload/v1457364436/arrow-right_oilpij.png">
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

So again, my thought was that I could have the .box class be a parent container and then the .text_container that would be nested could 're-size the text in a responsive manner in smaller viewports.  But it's not...and my hair is going grey.

Errggghhhh...

Answer (score 0):

child with the position absolute can't change the size or its parent or vice versa. Alternatively you can use the *float* property and set it to "right". Also, you might want to use % instead of pixels if you're aiming for a responsive design.

Comment: do you mean % for the text in the h1 class or set the font-size in the container class?

Comment: http://codepen.io/fitri/pen/oxbQJE check this alternative. It's best to use min-width on media query (mobile-first approach).

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/ 
`font-size` cannot do resize accroding to the windows's width, unless you define different font-size accroding to the width with [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)